# Escape powershell characters inside cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, escaping

I would like to execute a ping sweep, which is this powershell command:

```
$NET="192.168.111";for($i=1;$i -lt 255;$i++){$command="ping -n 1 -w 100 $NET.$i > nul 2>&1 && echo $NET.$i";start-process -nonewwindow "cmd" -argumentlist "/c $command" -redirectstandardoutput "tmp$i.txt"};cat tmp*.txt > sweep.txt
```

I need to do this inside cmd, I have already tried:

Wihout Quotes

```
powershell -c $NET="192.168.111";for($i=1;$i -lt 255;$i++){$command="ping -n 1 -w 100 $NET.$i > nul 2>&1 && echo $NET.$i";start-process -nonewwindow "cmd" -argumentlist "/c $command" -redirectstandardoutput "tmp$i.txt"};cat tmp*.txt > sweep.txt
```

With 1 doble quote

```
powershell -c "$NET="192.168.111";for($i=1;$i -lt 255;$i++){$command="ping -n 1 -w 100 $NET.$i > nul 2>&1 && echo $NET.$i";start-process -nonewwindow "cmd" -argumentlist "/c $command" -redirectstandardoutput "tmp$i.txt"};cat tmp*.txt > sweep.txt"
```

With 3 double quoutes

```
powershell -c """$NET="192.168.111";for($i=1;$i -lt 255;$i++){$command="ping -n 1 -w 100 $NET.$i > nul 2>&1 && echo $NET.$i";start-process -nonewwindow "cmd" -argumentlist "/c $command" -redirectstandardoutput "tmp$i.txt"};cat tmp*.txt > sweep.txt"""
```

Escaping the &&

```
powershell -c "$NET="192.168.111";for($i=1;$i -lt 255;$i++){$command="ping -n 1 -w 100 $NET.$i > nul 2>&1 \&\& echo $NET.$i";start-process -nonewwindow "cmd" -argumentlist "/c $command" -redirectstandardoutput "tmp$i.txt"};cat tmp*.txt > sweep.txt"
```

No success yet.

Thanks!

Comment: You should enclose your entire PowerShell command with doublequotes, to pass it as a single argument to powershell.exe. Then you need to escape the nested doublequote characters from cmd.exe parsing. For that, the escape character is the backward slash. e.g. `powershell "$NET=\"192.168.111\";for($i=1;$i -lt 255;$i++){$command=\"ping -n 1 -w 100 $NET.$i > nul 2>&1 && echo $NET.$i\";start-process -nonewwindow \"cmd\" -argumentlist \"/c $command\" -redirectstandardoutput \"tmp$i.txt\"};cat tmp*.txt > sweep.txt"`. _This assumes that the one liner you've provided works as is directly in PowerShell_

Comment: It doesn't work, missing } it says.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I used backticks before the quotes to escape. Even tho this could be accomplished with native Powershell commands but since you asked for something specific, here it is.

```
$NET="192.168.111"

for($i=1;$i -lt 255;$i++)
{
    $command="echo ########### && echo Pinging $NET.$i && ping -n 1 -w 100 $NET.$i 2>&1"
    start-process "cmd" -argumentlist "/c `"$command`"" -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput "tmp$i.txt"
}

while($true)
{
    if(-not (Get-Process cmd -EA SilentlyContinue))
    {
        cat tmp*.txt > sweep.txt
        break
    }
    sleep 5
}
```

Note that the `while` loop will wait for all cmd.exe processes to stop before breaking and unifying those files into `sweep.txt`. Remember to close any instance of cmd.exe you have opened before running this script or this loop will continue forever :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I forgot to say, on a oneliner ...

Comment: Sure, if you want a oneliner you can wrap all up using semicolons.

Comment: powershell -c $NET="192.168.111";for($i=1;$i -lt 255;$i++){$command="echo ########### && echo Pinging $NET.$i && ping -n 1 -w 100 $NET.$i 2>&1";start-process "cmd" -argumentlist "/c `"$command`"" -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput "tmp$i.txt"};while($true){if(-not (Get-Process cmd -EA SilentlyContinue)){cat tmp*.txt > sweep.txt;break}sleep 5}


I got missing semicolomn closing

Comment: Not sure I understand if this solved your problem or you still couldn't find out a solution.